# How does Stack Exchange deal with copies with translation?

Tags: discussion, copyright

There're a lot of Chinese websites that copies virtually all contents from Stack Overflow and translate them into Chinese (with machine translation of course, because they're of really a low quality). How should we deal with them?

Most of them copy by using a web spider.

Example: http://www.guanggua.com copies contents from Stack Overflow.